# Lowess method in statsmodels converts real values to NaN values. What is happening?

Tags: python, missing-data, statsmodels

I have a set of two-column dataframes and I want to generate smoothed estimates of the 2nd-column value for the given 1st-column value. The structure of a couple of the dataframes is like that:

```
         Mbp    cM
0  10.849607  64.5
1  10.864685  64.5
2  10.895010  64.5
3  10.988436  64.5
4  11.120783  66.6

[5 rows x 2 columns]

         Mbp    cM
0  11.153451  66.6
1  11.184827  66.6
2  11.185363  66.6
3  11.185411  66.6
4  11.185423  66.6

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

To do the smoothing I am using the [lowess](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html) method from the statsmodels python module. Below is the command line that I use for doing the smooting:

```
smoothed_subset = lowess(df_subset['Mbp'], df_subset['cM'])
```

However the ouput of the method converts all the values of the 'Mbp' column to `'nan'`. I cannot see the reason why. Below you can see the output for the two dataframes shown above.

```
[[ 64.5   nan]
 [ 64.5   nan]
 [ 64.5   nan]
 [ 64.5   nan]
 [ 66.6   nan]]
[[ 66.6   nan]
 [ 66.6   nan]
 [ 66.6   nan]
 [ 66.6   nan]
 [ 66.6   nan]]
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

`Editing:`

I run `repr(df_subset['Mbp'])` and `repr(df_subset['cM'])` for one of the dataframes as suggested by Alex W and below is the output:

```
0    10.849607
1    10.864685
2    10.895010
3    10.988436
4    11.120783
Name: Mbp, dtype: float64

0    64.5
1    64.5
2    64.5
3    64.5
4    66.6
Name: cM, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you do a `repr(df_subset['Mbp'])` and `repr(df_subset['cM'])` and post the results?

Comment: Based on the first sentence, I guess the arguments should be reversed, i.e. `lowess(df_subset['cM'], df_subset['Mbp'])`. statsmodels has by convention that the dependent variable comes first.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the optional parameters, just in case the defaults have changed.

I'm not sure how the algorithm works internally, but you may be suffering from having so many identical cM values.  Can you alter them slightly for testing purposes?  Even 1% might make a large difference in computability:

```
         Mbp    cM
0  10.849607  64.50
1  10.864685  64.51
2  10.895010  64.52
3  10.988436  64.53
4  11.120783  66.60

[5 rows x 2 columns]

         Mbp    cM
0  11.153451  66.61
1  11.184827  66.62
2  11.185363  66.63
3  11.185411  66.64
4  11.185423  66.65

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

I'm concerned that the NaN comes from a division by 0 somewhere.

Comment: Yes, there are some problems if too many values coincide https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2449 But it's not clear where exactly the problem comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the link user333700. It seems that the repetition of the same x-value generates a bug, together with the number of (x,y) pairs, where the bottom limit seems to be 50...

Comment: Thanks Prune. I will follow your advice. Need to do some modifications on my script by I will let you know if it works or not....

Comment: I modified the cM parameter but I am still getting `nans`....I think the problem could be the small size of my arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by setting the `it` parameter to 0, instead of the default value of 3.
The `it` parameter corresponds to the number of residual-based reweightings to perform.